# Continuity of a function with a product as domain

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that the following holds:

For every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, the functions

$f(x,.)\colon\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},$

$f(.,y)\colon\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},$

are continuous.

Is it then true that $f\colon \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true. Consider :

$$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 \dfrac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}& \text{ if } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\ 
 0 & \text{ otherwise } 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Then $f(x,.)$ and $f(.,y)$ are continuous for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.
In particular, $f(.,0)\equiv f(0,.) \equiv 0$. But now, if you approach $0$ by this path $y=x^2$, you get :

$$f(x,x^2)=\frac 1 2 \underset{x \to 0}\longrightarrow \frac 1 2$$

So $f$ is not continuous at $0$.